# Ansible: How to improve the 'win_copy' speed?

Tags: ansible, winrm

I use Ansible `win_copy` module to copy files from my Linux machine to my Windows server and it requires quite a lot of time
[(about 6 seconds an empty file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS5cT.png).

An [picure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGkMU.png)
of my Ansible playbook is linked.

Does anyone know how to improve the `win_copy` speed? Or should I use other ways to copy files from Linux to Windows?

I tried to use a list of small tasks on each file instead of `loop` function but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider zipping the files thus doing only one call to `win_copy` if `win_get_url` is not practical for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`win_copy` module – Copies files to remote locations on windows hosts - Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_copy_module.html#notes)

> *Because `win_copy` runs over WinRM, it is not a very efficient transfer mechanism. If sending large files consider hosting them on a web service and using [ansible.windows.win_get_url](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_get_url_module.html) instead.*

Regarding

> *I'm trying to send a few empty files. Is that the same issue?*

the latency comes from the fact that you are looping over a list of files causing opening and closing a connection for one file after the other. This is adding significant overhead and time to your task.

An apporach to avoid this is to ZIP the files and transmit them in one step and as [mentioned in the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76590385/6771046).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that but it says about large files and I'm trying to send a few empty files. Is that the same issue?